# How do you print a function's result in python?

Tags: python, function, boolean

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
    print(a+b)
def subtract(a,b):
    return a-b
    print(a-b)
def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b
    print(a*b)
def divide(a,b)
    return a/b
    print(a/b)

print('Please select an operation:')
print('1.Add')
print(2.Subtract')
print(3.Multiply')
print(4.Divide')
choice=input('Enter a choice\'1/2/3/4\')
a=int(input('Enter first number')
b=int(input('Enter second number')
if choice=='1':
#these are the sections that arent working
    add(a,b)
elif choice=='2':
#when run, it wont print the function even though Ive called it
    subtract(a,b)
elif choice=='3':
    multiply(a,b)
elif choice=='4':
    divide(a,b)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help with a solution. Thanks

Comment: `return` immediately leaves a function. You need your `return` after your `print` statements for the first four functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any code after a `return` statement in a function doesn't run.

If you want the print to be part of the function, you would have to do this:

```
def add(a,b):
    print(a+b)
    return a+b
def subtract(a,b):
    print(a-b)
    return a-b
def multiply(a,b):
    print(a*b)
    return a*b
def divide(a,b):
    print(a/b)
    return a/b
```

However, the much better way to do this would be to `print` the number that the function returns in your main function. For example:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
def subtract(a,b):
    return a-b
def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b
def divide(a,b):
    return a/b

print('Please select an operation:')
print('1.Add')
print('2.Subtract')
print('3.Multiply')
print('4.Divide')
choice = input("Enter a choice: '1/2/3/4'")
a = int(input('Enter first number'))
b = int(input('Enter second number'))    

if choice == '1':
    result = add(a, b)
elif choice == '2':
    result = subtract(a, b)
elif choice == '3':
    result = multiply(a, b)
elif choice == '4':
    result = divide(a, b)
print(result)
```

Comment: @Davina Great, I'm glad I could help. :) In that case, would you mind accepting my answer? You just click the check-mark by the voting arrows. It lets other people know that this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of `print` and `return` in all your functions

```
def divide(a,b)
    print(a/b)
    return a/b
```

Nothing in a function will execute after `return`, so none of your `print` statements will be reached.